# How can I change the identifier of each item in collection with lodash.keyBy?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a JSON string.

```
"1":{"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)","price":"13.55","sold":"444"},"2":{"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)","price":"38.96","sold":"157"}
```

and so on...

How can I remove the numbers (1,2,3,etc...), and use the "name" value to identify each item intead?
I've looked at lodash.keyBy, but I haven't been able to make "name" the identifier. The end goal is to be able to do call `obj[itemName]`- and receive the price.

Comment: What if... you have two objects with the exact same name but say with different i.e: price (or any other prop value)? have you thought about that (or it's not your concern?)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan no object has the same "name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lodash has a different method `_.mapKeys` which suits this a little better:

```js
const obj = {
  "1": {
    "name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
    "price":"13.55",
    "sold":"444"
  },
  "2":{
    "name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)",
    "price":"38.96",
    "sold":"157"
  }
}

console.log(_.mapKeys(obj, (val) => val.name));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
x = x={"1":{"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)","price":"13.55","sold":"444"},"2":{"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)","price":"38.96","sold":"157"} }
_.reduce(x, (acc,o) => {acc[o.name] = o; return acc;}, {})
```

If you want, you can also remove the "name" from the resultant key, and also create a *copy* of the original instead of reference.

```
_.reduce(x, (acc,o) => {acc[o.name] = Object.assign({},o); delete acc[o.name].name; return acc;}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be done with `_.keyBy`?  How about with `_.each` and `_.omit`? (`_.omit` makes the assumption you don't need the `name` key/value pair anymore)

```
var before = {"1":{"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)","price":"13.55","sold":"444"},"2":{"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)","price":"38.96","sold":"157"}};
var after = {};

_.each(before, function(b4) {
  after[b4.name] = _.omit(b4, 'name');
});
```

See: https://repl.it/@dexygen/stackoverflowq48085676

Answer (score -2):

This gives you the whole item by giving a specific name.

```
var jsonArray = [{name: "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)", price: "38.96", sold: "157"}, {name: "Glock-18 | Fade (Factory New)", price: "287,10", sold: "256"}];

function match(x) {
return x[this[0]]===this[1];
}

var nameToCheck = "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)"

var getObject = jsonArray.filter(match, ["name", nameToCheck]);

console.log(getObject);
```

If you want the price, you just do:

```
var price = getObject[0].price;
```

Comment: each item is identified by a number... I want to remove the numbers and use "name" to identify each item instead.

Comment: The collection has over 10000 items.

Comment: @Reyni Updated, try now!

Comment: @Reyni All you need to change is the variable `nameToCheck` to the name you want to get the price of.